# how to smooth my gridview scrolling in android?

Tags: android, gridview, android-viewholder

i am use a class by below code for gridview. how i can smooth my gridview scrolling by viewholder or other method?
i want just my scrolling gridview performance very smoothly. i use this gridview for show images and names and by click on eacj item open another activity for detail about.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomGrid extends BaseAdapter{

private Context mContext;
private final String[] web;
private final int[] Imageid;


public CustomGrid(Context c, String[] web, int[] Imageid) {
    mContext = c;
    this.Imageid = Imageid;
    this.web = web;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return web.length;
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View grid;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)         mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    grid = new View(mContext);
    grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
    TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
    textView.setText(web[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[position]);


    return grid;
}
}
```

Comment: Use viewHolder pattern

Comment: As a note to what @d1vivek681065 already said, you have to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works . Just make sure that you understand why it was  sooo slow. Fixing only the problem will not solve the real isssue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always try to use ViewHolder Pattern for lists and girds this improves the performance of Lists and Grids :

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if(convertView==null){
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item,parent,false);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else {
        viewHolder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    viewHolder.image=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    viewHolder.title=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    viewHolder.title.setText(Html.fromHtml(values.getPosts().get(position).getTitle()));

    imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[position]);
    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder{
    public static ImageView image;
    public static TextView title;
}
```